# remove rows and columns from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],
[6,0,8,9,10],
[11,12,13,14,15],
[16,0,0,19,20]])
```

And I would like to remove columns and rows where there is a `0` value, so the new `a` should be like:

```
array([[1,4,5],
[11,14,15]])
```

How to work this out using indexing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> a[(a != 0).all(axis=1)][:,(a != 0).all(axis=0)]
array([[ 1,  4,  5],
       [11, 14, 15]])
```

Finding the elements of `a` that are non-zero is really easy:

```
>>> (a != 0)
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

And then you can just use `all`, specifying the axis, to find the rows you want to keep:

```
>>> (a != 0).all(axis=1)
array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

and the same thing for the columns:

```
>>> (a != 0).all(axis=0)
array([ True, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!